# Can we add careeroverflow.com to the "belongs on" list when voting to close?

Tags: feature-request

People continue to ask career and job related questions (this morning it was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591113/how-do-programmers-get-started-without-a-college-background) in the jobs tag) and when closing them we can only mark them off topic. If we could migrate them to career overflow that might increase the traffic and action there, while also leaving the "migrated to" comment to teach SO people where they should take those questions.

Answer (score 6):

As careeroverflow.com is a SE 1.0 site that is based on a totally different software release this might not be possible. And as you can see from [this announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/migration-of-se-1-0-sites/) about the migration of SE 1.0 sites, their existence in the future are yet to be determined. With 379 questions and 558 users (2/3 of them with a rep of 1) as of today (8/28/2010) I would not count on this site to survive. Maybe there will be a SE 2.0 proposal that will be more suited to migrate to.